# foggy headlight wet sand & rustoleum 2X plastic clear coat

Tags: lights

What is causing cracks in my head light after Rustoleum Plastic clearcoat

Comment: After Wetsanding 400,100,2000 grit

Comment: Did you wipe the lenses with alcohol before applying the clear coat? If not, that's why it's cracking.

Comment: @user9181 - Yes w/isopropel alchohol 70%...

Comment: never use alcohol on lenses - it makes them crack and fog